# tfpt unable to determine the workspace

Tags: visual-studio, tfs-power-tools

I am trying to unshelve a shelveset from one Workspace to another.
Both on visual studio online.
Running such a command 
`tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:"randomname.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection\Project\Branch1" /target:"randomname.visualstudio.com\DefaultCollection\Project\Branch2" "random_shelveset_name"` would result the exception Unable to determin the workspace

The command looks exactly as have been typed in the commandline (the structure of it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run tf.exe from the command line and run the command:

```
tf workspaces /s:serverURL
```

serverUR being your server information

I had the same issue and had trouble running tf.exe by double-clicking or calling the command without starting tf.exe first